# Looking to do a find and replace using PowerShell via a csv file

Tags: powershell, foreach, import-csv

Hit a roadblock looking to just do a find and replace of a string using files listed in a csv. Example what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$inputfiles = Import-Csv D:\temp\testfolder\test.csv
$find = 'shazaam'
$replace ='shazaam1234'

foreach ($inputfile in $inputfiles) {

(Get-Content $PSItem.FullName) -Replace $oldString,$newString | Set-Content -Path 
$PSItem.FullName
}
```

Comment: Please show us a portion of your csv file.  That will help us figure out what you code is doing.

Comment: Here is a example :  D:\temp\testfolder\sqlload

D:\temp\testfolder\sqlload_mask

Comment: PLEASE, add the info to your Question, not in a comment. not only is the comment easy to overlook ... it is often quite hard to read. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

If the first Line of your csv is 'Fullname' then the following script should work.

```
# Import files with import csv (if first line isn't 'FullName' use Get-Content instead)
$inputfiles = Import-Csv D:\temp\testfolder\test.csv
$find = 'shazaam'
$replace ='shazaam1234'

# iterate through inputfiles
$inputfiles.Foreach({
    # use .Replace instead because it uses no regular expressions
    (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Replace($find,$replace) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
})
```